# Error in Compiling OpenGL code under Windows

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-errors, compilation, g++

I am trying to compile an OpenGL program.

This is the portion of the code with all the includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
// Usage of degrees is deprecated. Use radians for glm functions.
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include "shaders.h"
```

The file i am trying to run is called `mytest1.cpp` and i also have `shaders.h` in the same directory.

In the same directory i have a folder called `'include'` And inside two subfolders called `'GL'` and `'glm'` with all the files inside that are required from the program.

So i go to the directory of the `mytest1.cpp` and i type `g++ mytest1.cpp` and i get the error:

```
mytest1.cpp:14:21: fatal error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
 #include <GL/glew.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

Why does this happen? I also tried to place the `'GL'` folder in the root directory and i got the same error

Comment: It happened because in the places that the compiler is looking for header files there is no file called `GL/glew.h`, not sure what else there is to say. You need to read your compiler documentation to find out what process you need to follow to tell the compiler where to find the header files. Note this is almost certainly better than copying files around. Put the header files where you think they should go, and tell the compiler where to find them. Since you are using g++, that would be to use the `-I` option.

Comment: From your description, you should compile and link with `g++ -I./include mytest1.cpp`. For further questions
about invoking GCC, refer first to [An Introduction to GCC](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/index.html)
and [the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)

Comment: Thanks , at elast it compiles now but i has many errors of undefined referenecs, which there are not in  my code